# AFTER parameter not recognized as part of CREATE TASK

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a task and verified that it exists using `SHOW TASKS`. I'm now trying to create a subtask using the `AFTER` parameter of [`CREATE TASK`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html), but I'm getting the following error: `invalid property 'AFTER' for 'TASK'`. I can't find any documentation on why this is happening. I think my syntax is correct; it appears to match Snowflake's documentation. This is my code:

```
//Create the task and set the schedule
CREATE TASK NIGHTLY_1
  WAREHOUSE = ADMIN_WH
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 02 * * * America/Chicago'
AS
CALL SP_LOAD_STAGING_TABLE('param1');

//Create the subtask 
CREATE TASK NIGHTLY_2
  WAREHOUSE = ADMIN_WH
  AFTER = NIGHTLY_1
AS
CALL SP_LOAD_STAGING_TABLE('param2');
```

The notes on the `AFTER` param state (my emphasis):

> The root task in a tree of tasks **must be suspended** before any task in the tree is recreated (using the CREATE OR REPLACE TASK syntax) **or a child task is added** (using CREATE TASK … AFTER).

I've verified with `SHOW TASKS` that the parent task is suspended.

Any thoughts on what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equal sign should be removed `AFTER = NIGHTLY_1`:

```
//Create the subtask 
CREATE TASK NIGHTLY_2
  WAREHOUSE = ADMIN_WH
  AFTER NIGHTLY_1
AS
CALL SP_LOAD_STAGING_TABLE('param2');
```

---

[CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html):

> ```
> AFTER <string>
> ```
>
> Specifies the predecessor task for the current task. When a run of the predecessor task finishes successfully, it triggers this task (after a brief lag).

The same rule applies to ALTER:

```
ALTER TASK [ IF EXISTS ] <name> REMOVE AFTER <string> | ADD AFTER <string>
```